# Check if two values of a column in each group follow each other

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset as follow:

```
 id  date        customer_id
 1   02/03/2018   undefined
 1   04/23/2018   12
 1   05/22/2018   12
 1   06/25/2018   undefined
 2   01/14/2017   undefined
 2   02/23/2018   undefined
 2   03/04/2018   23
 2   04/04/2018   23
```

I want to group this data by id, and sort, within the group by date. Now here is the part I can not figure out. I want a way to check that for each sorted group, customer_id's value of "undefined"s are followed by numbers, meaning that in the above case, id == 2 is what I want to keep, because it has its "undefined"s together and after that we only have the number. The idea is when customer_id is undefined, they are not customers but in time, as soon as they become customers, the "value" changes to a number which is customer id. So in this case, the id == 1 is a bad record and I want to discard it and keep only id == 2.

```
data %>% group_by(id) %>%
         arrange(date) %>% "code to keep only records that have all 
         the undefined in customer_id together and after only numbers,
         in this case, I want to only keep id == 2 records"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(diff(row_number()[customer_id == 'undefined']) == 1) & customer_id[n()] != 'undefined')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
     id date       customer_id
  <int> <fct>      <fct>      
1     2 01/14/2017 undefined  
2     2 02/23/2018 undefined  
3     2 03/04/2018 23         
4     2 04/04/2018 23
```

This code presumes that your data frame is already arranged. Otherwise:

```
df %>%
  arrange(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(diff(row_number()[customer_id == 'undefined']) == 1) &
           customer_id[n()] != 'undefined')
```

Basically, what we do is check for each group whether differences between row numbers for the `undefined` cases are always 1 (i.e. they are sequential), and whether the last value is not `undefined`.

Records like these are kept (`id` 2 in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by checking whether the run length encoding of the `customer_id` column is 2 or 1, meaning that the id did not become defined or undefined more than once:

```
data <- read.table(text="id  date        customer_id
                   1   02/03/2018   undefined
                   1   04/23/2018   12
                   1   05/22/2018   12
                   1   06/25/2018   undefined
                   2   01/14/2017   undefined
                   2   02/23/2018   undefined
                   2   03/04/2018   23
                   2   04/04/2018   23", header = T, stringsAsFactors=F)

data$date <- as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
data$customer_id <- as.integer(data$customer_id)

data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(date, .by_group=T) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(length(rle(is.na(customer_id))$values < 3) && !is.na(tail(customer_id, 1))) 

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
     id date       customer_id
  <int> <date>           <int>
1     2 2017-01-14          NA
2     2 2018-02-23          NA
3     2 2018-03-04          23
4     2 2018-04-04          23
```

Note that you also have to make sure that the last item of each group is valid, otherwise groups that go from a valid id to `undefined` will pass the test.